# Probability that one is a male

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

i have the following question: A lady gave birth to a triplet, you know that at least one of them is male. You met her on the street with one child, what's the probability that he's a male?
I'm trying to do this by definition so i said:
$|\Omega| = 2^3$, the events are $A=$("at least one is a male") and $B=$("you met a male"). $P(A)=\frac78$ and $|B|=?$ and i want to calculate $P(B|A)$. That's where i get stuck. Can anyone offer an explanation?

Comment: The probability that '*he*'s a male' is 1! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a $3/7$ chance of one male child, a $3/7$ chance of two, and a $1/7$ chance of three, so the total probability is $\left(\dfrac{1}{3} \times \dfrac{3}{7}\right) + \left(\dfrac{2}{3} \times \dfrac{3}{7}\right) + \left( \dfrac{3}{3} \times \dfrac{1}{7} \right) = \dfrac{4}{7}.$ Alternatively, if you want Bayes' theorem, $P(\text{meeting a boy}) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ if you know nothing about the woman's family, $P(\text{at least one boy}) = \dfrac{7}{8}$ if you haven't met any of the woman's children, and of course $P(\text{at least one boy}|\text{meeting a boy}) = 1$, so by Bayes,
$$P(\text{meeting a boy}|\text{at least one boy}) = \frac{P(\text{meeting a boy}) P(\text{at least one boy}|\text{meeting a boy})}{P(\text{at least one boy})} = \frac{ (1/2) \times (1)}{7/8} = \frac{4}{7}.$$

For the question you ask in comments, "Given that you met a (presumably randomly selected) boy, what's the chance that she has at least one girl?" $$P(\text{at least one girl}|\text{meeting a boy}) = \frac{P(\text{at least one girl}) P(\text{meeting a boy}|\text{at least one girl})}{P(\text{meeting a boy})}.$$ The prior probabilities $P(\text{at least one girl}) = 7/8$ and $P(\text{meeting a boy}) = 1/2$, same as above, and $P(\text{meeting a boy}|\text{at least one girl})$ is the same (by symmetry) as $P(\text{meeting a girl}|\text{at least one boy})$, which is $3/7$, the complement of the probability that we calculated in the first problem. The probability is $\dfrac{(7/8) \times (3/7)}{1/2} = \dfrac{3}{4}$. Alternatively, taking a page from drhab's answer here, of the seven equally likely triplets BBB BBG BGB BGG GBB GBG GGB, there are $12$ boys of whom $9$ appear with at least one girl, and $9/12 = 3/4$.

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for a solution that uses bayes. I have another question regarding this one, and it would be a waste to open a new topic for that. "Given that you've met a male, what's the probability that the lady has also a female?". I'm trying to use bayes for that but i always reach a probability greater than 1. Could you give me a hint on how to approach this?

Comment: See main answer.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can think of 8 triplets (BBB,BBG, et cetera).

Symmetrically there are $12$ boys and $12$ girls.

Now the triple GGG is taken away so that $12$ boys and $9$ girls remain all having equal probability to be met on the street.

That gives probability $\frac{12}{12+9}=\frac47$ to meet a boy.

Comment: +1: This is a useful trick for dealing with probabilities.

Comment: Ooh, this is clever.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on *how* "you know that at least one of them is male".

Here are two different types of scenarios:

1. Someone one day just told you that this woman had a triplet and that 'at least one of them is a boy'
2. You met this woman some day before on the street (or store, or ..) and she had 1 child with her that was a boy, and she told you this was one of a triplet that she had

Notice that in both scenarios you know that she had a triplet and that at least one of them is male.

In scenario 1 (which I would guess is what the book/instructor is looking for), you use the calculation used by ConnorHarris, since out of the 8 possible and initially equally likely triplets (MMM, MMF, MFM, FMM, MFF, FMF, FFM, FFF), you can rule out the FFF one, so you have a $\frac{3}{7}$ chance of one male and two females, a $\frac{3}{7}$ chance of two male and one female, and a $\frac{1}{7}$ chance of all three being male, and so the probability of the one child being with her today being male is:

$\left(\dfrac{1}{3} \times \dfrac{3}{7}\right) + \left(\dfrac{2}{3} \times \dfrac{3}{7}\right) + \left( \dfrac{3}{3} \times \dfrac{1}{7} \right) = \dfrac{4}{7}.$

In scenario 2 (which is actually a far more likely kind of scenario to happen in the real world; indeed, note that you are meeting her *today* in that exact kind of situation ...), there is a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance that both other children are female, a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance that there is one more male and one more female, and a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance that both other children are male. In other words, there is a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance of one male and two females, a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of two male and one female, and a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance of all three being male.

So now you get that the probability of the one child with her today being male is:

$\left(\dfrac{1}{3} \times \dfrac{1}{4}\right) + \left(\dfrac{2}{3} \times \dfrac{1}{2}\right) + \left( \dfrac{3}{3} \times \dfrac{1}{4} \right) = \dfrac{2}{3}.$

In sum: the question is actually ambiguous, and even though the book is most likely looking for the answer compatible with scenario 1, if a situation like this ever comes up in real life, you are more likely to deal with a scenario 2 type situation!